# Error: "metadata generation failed", can't install Ultralytics Module

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install Utralytics on raspberrypi model 4 with 4G RAM and with bullseye raspberryOS.
when i want to install with below comand:

pip install ultralytics

i take below error.
i tried this command too:

pyhton3 -m pip install ultralytics

but i take same error.
i update pip,setuptools,wheel.
how can i fix it.

```
      ../../meson.build:63:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['nvfortran'], ['pgfortran'], ['ifort'], ['ifx'], ['g95']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running `gfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
  Running `gfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
  Running `flang --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
  Running `flang -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
  Running `nvfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
  Running `nvfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
  Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
  Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
  Running `ifort --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
  Running `ifort -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
  Running `ifx --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
  Running `ifx -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
  Running `g95 --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
  Running `g95 -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
  
  A full log can be found at /tmp/pip-install-vpm4le6w/scipy_fa8642477d2a4052aa580a87c2367cda/.mesonpy-wae33bni/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
  + meson setup --prefix=/usr /tmp/pip-install-vpm4le6w/scipy_fa8642477d2a4052aa580a87c2367cda /tmp/pip-install-vpm4le6w/scipy_fa8642477d2a4052aa580a87c2367cda/.mesonpy-wae33bni/build --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-vpm4le6w/scipy_fa8642477d2a4052aa580a87c2367cda/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to first install gfortran try,

```
sudo apt install gfortran
```

If Ultralytics calls for a specific version, you can see them below:
https://fortran-lang.org/en/learn/os_setup/install_gfortran/